# sound_play.h not in included in ros-hydro-sound-play?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, sound-play, ros-fuerte, audio-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, I am migrating my ros package from fuerte(rosbuild) to hydro(catkin). Even though the ros sound_play package is installed and runs properly, it seems the `sound_play.h` file is not included in the package anymore.

I worked around this problem by moving the file manually, but...

Can someone tell me whether this is intended and, if yes, the reason about this? The `class SoundClient` provided through this header file seems to be a very convenient tool to work with the sound_play node.

Thank you in advance!
Adrian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100941/sound_play.h-not-in-included-in-ros-hydro-sound-play?/) by [EddiEdward](https://answers.ros.org/users/8791/eddiedward/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is a bug in the sound_play package. I have created a ticket here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/issues/27

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EddiEdward](https://answers.ros.org/users/8791/eddiedward/) on 2013-11-13**:
Thanks for your answer and the opened ticket!